# Error beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1 while using Apache Beam io.jdbc.ReadFromJdbc

Tags: python, jdbc, apache-beam

I'm trying to read from a postgres table using Apache beam's python SDK. I have installed the Java SDK as the documentation says. I'm using the latest release.
My code stands as follows:

```
import logging
import typing

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam import coders
from apache_beam.io.jdbc import ReadFromJdbc
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from past.builtins import unicode


def run(argv=None):
    beam_options = PipelineOptions()

    ExampleRow = typing.NamedTuple('ExampleRow', [('id', int), ('name', unicode)])

    coders.registry.register_coder(ExampleRow, coders.RowCoder)

    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
        result = (
            p
            | 'Read from jdbc' >> ReadFromJdbc(
                                    table_name='jdbc_external_test_read',
                                    driver_class_name='org.postgresql.Driver',
                                    jdbc_url='jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/example',
                                    username='postgres',
                                    password='postgres')
        )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.getLogger(__name__).setLevel(logging.INFO)
    run()
```

But when I run it I get the error `ValueError: No logical type registered for URN 'beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1'`

Comment: Same problem here :(

Comment: What is the schema of the `jdbc_external_test_read` table?

Comment: I'm guessing the `name` field is either `VARCHAR` or `TEXT`.  I'm encountering the same problem with Postgres with text fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is caused because the `VARCHAR` field is returned as an Apache Beam [Logical Type](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#logical-types) in it's schema. Logical types are denoted by their URN's, in this case `beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1`. For logical types, a "decoder" has to be registered for corresponding URN to read the value. You can do that as follows:

```py
from apache_beam.typehints.schemas import LogicalType

@LogicalType.register_logical_type
class db_str(LogicalType):
    @classmethod
    def urn(cls):
        return "beam:logical_type:javasdk:v1"

    @classmethod
    def language_type(cls):
        return str

    def to_language_type(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def to_representation_type(self, value):
        return str(value)
```

This has to be done before running the pipeline, so the logical type will be recognized as string and converted to string.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is fixed in Beam v2.44.0 onwards, as JdbcIO migrated to use portable logical types for VARCHAR/TEXT (and CHAR, BINARY, TIMESTAMP, DECIMAL are also supported)